# Import xml data in datastax Graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have data in my xml files. I need to save that data in datastax graph. but didn't find any link to import xml into dse graph. I have read about GraphML. can GraphML do this if yes please let me know how?

Comment: The DataStax Graph Loader provides support for all kinds of sources including graphML https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglGRAPHML.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes GraphML should be able to do what you want.  You would just need to make sure your input data lines up correctly.  I would recommend looking into [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createSchemaGraphML.html) as it goes a bit more in depth.

Comment: but for creating nodes and edges i have to provide member_id and community_id. how i can provide  these values?